# Convergence of $\sum_{i=0}^{\log_2(n)} (\frac{3}{2})^i$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I have to solve the recurrence $T(n) = 3T(\frac{n}{2}) + n$ by using recursion tree. By applying this method I came to

$$T(n) = \sum_{i=0}^{\log_2(n)} (\frac{3}{2})^i$$

Since $|\frac{3}{2}| > 1$, I can not use convergence of geometric series for this problem. What else can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Use the closed form for the sum a finite geometric series: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Closed-form_formula

Comment: @Gary thanks, that solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

As Gary said, the closed-form for a geometric series easily solves the problem to give you $T(n)=\frac{\bigl(\frac{3}{2}\bigr)^{\log_2(n)+1}-1}{\frac{3}{2}-1}=2\bigl(\frac{3}{2}\bigr)^{\log_2(n)+1}-2.$